# My computer turns on after hibernate

Tags: windows-8, bios, hibernate

I'm not going crazy or anything but after I hibernate my PC it just decides to turn back on again without me doing anything. I have checked my BIOS and it shows nothing that will turn it back on.

Any suggestions on what I should check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open start > run > cmd and type (or type cmd directly from search): `powercfg /lastwake`
This will show you from what was the computer waked. 
If it was a device, type: `powercfg –devicequery [device]`. The device will show at the bottom of the results from the first command.

P.S.
I'm assuming you don't have any peripheral connected...

Comment: Is this the answer or not? Don't mark it an answer until you have verified.

Comment: @Moab yes I did this and found out what was turning it back on. I've fixed it now

Comment: I'm glad everything is fine now! :)